# In CartoDB, can columns (e.g. ARPU2011) have descriptions (e.g. Average Revenue Per User 2011)

Tags: carto

I have an in-house database with spatial data (Postgres + PostGIS) for which I'm generating an extract (GeoJSON/KML etc) in order to load it into CartoDB.

My column names are technical (e.g. ARPU2011, or even less clear, and I need this to remain that way) but I also have column descriptions available (e.g. "Average Revenue Per User 2011").

Using which export format and what type of formatting can I then later find both the technical name and the description usable for filtering in CartoDB?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of searching in multiple places, I believe it is not yet possible. See [GitHub issue - Suggestion: Allow adding a description for column information](https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb/issues/5445)

Comment: Hi Thibaut, you are right, it's not possible.
I'm going to think about it and see if we can add it to the backlog.

Happy Mapping!

Comment: Hi Sergio - thanks for the quick answer and for considering this to your roadmap!